# Divide long controller into small controllers in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

I am working on complex application and every controller has more than 2000 lines.
Can anyone suggest to break the codes into small controllers and used as a dependency on main controller.

Comment: why you are not going to service logic ? move your functionality into services

Comment: The controllers are very long.. I need to implement parent child concept.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple controller to handle the task in your page.If you are using long controller you can split the definition to multiple files by passing the scope to another method and then define the rest of methods there.

In the first file:

```
app.controller('CtrlA', function($scope){
app.expandControllerA($scope);

});
```

In the second file

```
app.expandControllerA = function($scope)
{

}
```

You can pass any variable or dependencies to expandControllerA function.